# Django ImageField doesn't take default value

Tags: django, django-models

I have an Imagefield in a model, I have set a default in it as well, I am doing a get_or_create in which if the Imagefield is passed as None, I get back the field as  in the model instance and not as django default field.

Isn't it a wrong behavior? If I don't pass a None field, I get back instance having the default field.

Answer (score 0):

[default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#default) is used in the python side when the model object is created (note it can be also callable). It is not something which is propagated to the database or replaces null or blank values.

Comment: So, when instantiating a model, doesnt equating None to a field equivalent to sending no value to that field?

Comment: I think it is not the same. If you pass None it will set it no None. If you don't give any value, it will take the default value. You can look at the code here https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py, line 426-430